# 2 users remoting into one workstation

Tags: remote-desktop, webserver, vnc

Can 2 users remote into one workstation or pc using vnc or remote desktop?
Strictly for training or troubleshooting purposes.
Both users view the same screen but one only observes while the other has control of keyboard & mouse.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but a simple way is only user1 uses remote destkop and shares his screen with user2 using Teams or equivalent.

Comment: What OS?  Windows?

Comment: You can try it with Radmin Server on the host machine and Radmin clients on the other machine. See if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Been doing that for years...

Have 1 user connect by Remote Desktop. This is the operator that controls the PC.
Have the 2nd user connect by VNC. It is recommended to configure the VNC server for readonly-mode so the VNC connected user can't mess with the keyboard/mouse.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows this is straight-forward :

- User 1 does RDP into the workstation
- User 2 observes user 1 via TeamViewer or similar.